# Get model data in table row to controller/model if the radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I'm dynamically making table rows that have radio buttons in them. I want the user to be able to select a radio button, and that is the information that is added to the model.

**HTML**

Ok so I have a table that starts out entirely empty. When the user searches for the customer, the table will add lines (upon clicking the search button). But to start, this is what we have:

```
    <div class="row border mt-3 p-3" id="policyInfo">
    <div class="input-group mb-3 ">
        <h3 class="col-lg-12 blue redUnderline">Policy Information</h3>
    </div>

    <TABLE class="table mt-3" id="policyTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PolicyTypes)</th>
                <th scope="col">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.policyID)</th>
                <th scope="col">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PolicyExpirationDate)</th>
                <th scope="col"> @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PolicyStatus)</th>
                <th scope="col"> @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Agency)</th>
                <th scope="col"> @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AgencyCert)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <TR></TR>
    </TABLE>

</div>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

**JQUERY/AJAX**

My JQuery/Ajax/Controller talk to the controller which talks to the database and based off of a name/email provided it returns data and asks my JavaScript function to create a new row.

```
    $('#search').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "/Home/PolicyID_get",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            Firstname: $('#firstname').val(),
            Lastname: $('#lastname').val(),
            Email: $('#email').val(),
        },
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (i, result) {
                addRowsPolicyHolder("policyTable", result.Policyid, result.PolicyStatus, result.PolicyExpirationDate, result.Agencycode, null);

            });

        }
    });
});
```

**JavaScript**
My JS checks to see if a row id number exists (like if the first row exists, etc) and makes a new row number based on that. The code below only shows how the radio button and the policy ID are made, but the rest of the table row is in my code.

```
function addRowsPolicyHolder(tableId, policyId, policyStatus, policyExp, certifyingAgency, agencyCertId) {
var iteration = 0;
var stop = false;

while (stop == false) {
    var elementChk = "[" + iteration + "].policyID";
    var checkId = document.getElementById(elementChk);
    if (checkId) {
        stop = false;
    } else {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableId);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element0 = document.createElement("input");
        var element0Label = document.createElement("label");
        var element0Span = document.createElement("span");
        element0Label.className = "radioContainer";
        element0Span.className = "checkmark";
        element0.type = "radio";
        element0.id = "[" + iteration + "].chkbox";
        element0.name = "policyCheckBox";
        element0Label.appendChild(element0);
        element0Label.appendChild(element0Span);
        cell0.appendChild(element0Label);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "text";
        element1.id = "[" + iteration + "].policyID";
        element1.name = "[" + iteration + "].policyID";
        element1.className = "form-control";
        element1.disabled = true;
        element1.value = policyId;
        cell1.appendChild(element1);
```

But, we have the controller set up to return a list of customers, not just the first result, since customers can have more than one policy. If more than one policy is returned, multiple lines will be returned. Additionally, let's say someone comes in with their spouse and we search their info, but they also want to see if their spouse has a better policy. We can search for multiple people and multiple policies will show up.

***All of this works fine. I just can't figure out how to ONLY send the row that is checked to the model.***

I found some solutions that use razor syntax to do this, but since I'm creating rows dynamically, I can't get it to work.

Comment: So when they click Continue, it submits a form (not included in code) that corresponds to a post controller action?  If so, can you make the dynamically added rows not correspond to model names, and instead, when you click continue, loop through each row and add hidden inputs to the form only for checked items?

Comment: So instead of having the input boxes correspond to the model, have them do their own thing? Then if it's selected, add the value to hidden inputs?

Comment: Yes, if your goal is to avoid posting them.  You could also handle it on the controller side and/or with some sort of custom binding.

Comment: Ok it took a couple code changes, but that worked! If you post it as a solution I'll vote for it. For anyone else reading this, I basically set the input boxes as their own thing (not part of the model), and then upon submission, whichever one is check autofills hidden boxes that are part of the model.

Comment: I didn't really provide any code, just a general direction.  I suggest you post your final code and accept it as an answer instead.  Glad it worked.